# How to change admin URL in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Remember that the **Magento admin panel** is currently accessible through

**http://www.localhost.com/magento/admin** 
or **http://www.yourdomain.com/admin**,

using your own domain name.

But there’s a downside to this. Having the Magento admin panel reachable in the same way for **all Magento stores on the web is a security risk. Hackers wil know where to find your admin panel and that’s one of the first steps to get access**. So, it’s better to change this path. Doing so requires some additional, and more difficult steps. You can find some good instructions using the following

Comment: Can you please rephrase this as a question.

Comment: how to change the admin url in magento? to save from hacker

Comment: Please edit the question body using this link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38741115/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from either of the two ways stated below:-

```
1) Changing local.xml
2) Changing Admin URL from Magento Backend Admin Settings
```

1) Changing local.xml

– Open app/etc/local.xml
– Find the following:-

```
<admin>
    <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
</admin>


<admin>
    <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
</admin>
```

– Change to your desired name. Like:-

– **Save the file**
– **Refresh the Cache from Magento Admin (System -> Cache Management)**

Now, you should be able to access admin panel **from http://www.example.com/backend/ instead of http://www.example.com/admin/**